# Excel Power Query Load Times - Why do dependent queries reload CSV file data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, power-query

I have a series of queries in Excel which all depend on an initial query which loads data from CSV files, processes them and loads them into a table in the worksheet.  The remaining queries all use worksheet tables as a source and don't utilize external datasources.

When I reload them individually them seem to take longer than they should and appear to be accessing the CSV files themselves.

I have all of the global and data settings for query to optimize loading (fast load, turn off background, etc.) based on some internet research and the original query loading/processing is acceptable given the amount of data.  It would just seem that once I have the processed data in a table in the workbook that queries of that table and others would not require going back to datasource files.

Just wondering if I am missing something here.  Thanks!

Comment: How are you reloading the queries individually?

Comment: Your first paragraph doesnt make much sense. Either the "remaining queries" "all depend on an initial query" or they dont. Which is it?

Comment: Yes Gangula, I usually reload queries individually since the data in the proximate queries does not generally change.

Comment: Thanks Mike, let me clarify. The dependent queries use the initial queries as their data source, typically using the "Manage/Reference" button in the Power Query Editor toolbar which generates a source = #"<parent query>.  Only the independent query using external CSV files as a data source using the Get Data button in the main Excel Data toolbar which generates a series of queries and function to load the data from the files into a table. I assumed that refreshing the dependent query would simply access the independent query (unrefreshed) table and not access the CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

When a query references another query as a Source (or in a Merge or Append step), that entire Source query logic will run every time the referencing query is refreshed.  If you have 5 queries referencing the same Source query, the Source query logic will be run 5 times, in parallel (by default). It's obviously inefficient.

In an Excel scenario, the pattern to avoid that inefficiency is to set the Source query to **Load To** an Excel table. Then the referencing queries can be pointed at that Excel table as their Source.

That does leaves you with a challenge to co-ordinate the refreshes, as hitting the Refresh All button risks inconsistent results. I typically mitigate that using Query Groups or by recording a refresh Macro.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mike.  You appear to be correct, although refreshing a dependent query does seem to refresh the parent query (as confirmed by messages about which CSV files it is accessing) somewhat quicker than refreshing the parent query directly.

I have solved the problem the way you suggested.  Instead of using the "Manage/Reference" button in the Power Query Editor toolbar which generates

Source = #"parent query"

I use Get Data->Table/Range or M editor to get data from parent query's table

Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="parent query table name"]}[Content]

Now loads instantly. As I am in the development phase of my project, managing refreshes is not an issue.  Will figure out a system once I am done.

Thanks!